# Get all values of custom input inside v-for vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I created a vuejs custom input that I wanted to use to dynamically display inputs by using props within the custom input. I haven't shown them here because it would be too long.

By clicking on the submit button, which is also part of the custom input, I wanna be able to get the values of each input, but for some reason, I have only been able to get the value of the last input.
What am I doing wrong?

Custom input:

```
<template>
    <div class="form-input">
        <label :label="label" :for="name" v-if="label && type !='submit' ">{{label}} <span v-if="required">*</span></label>
        <a v-if="multiple" href="#" class="btn">Upload</a>
        <input v-model="inputVal" :multiple="multiple" v-if="type != 'textarea' && type != 'submit'" class="form-control" :required="required" :class="classes" :type="type" :name="name" :placeholder="placeHolder">
        <textarea v-model="inputVal" :multiple="multiple" v-else-if="type != 'submit'" class="form-control" :required="required" :class="classes" :type="type" :name="name" :placeholder="placeHolder"></textarea>
        <button :multiple="multiple" :name="name" v-else type="submit">{{label}}</button>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: "Input",
    data () {
        return {
            inputVal: null
        }
    },
    watch: {
        inputVal: {
            handler: function(newValue, oldValue) {
                this.$emit('input', newValue);
            },
            deep: true,
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Form where custom input is used:

```
<template>
    <div class="form container">
        <form v-on:submit.prevent="sendMail" method="post" class="d-flex row shadow bg-dark border-right border-dark">
            <h3 class="col-12">Contact me</h3>
            <Input v-model="formInput" v-for="input in inputs"  v-bind:key="input.name" :label="input.label" :multiple="input.multiple" :type="input.type" :name="input.name" :class="input.classes" :required="input.required"></Input>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import Input from "../components/Input";
export default {
    name: "Contact",
    components: {Input},
    data() {
        return {
            formInput: null,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        sendMail () {
            console.log(this.formInput);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue I see in your code is, you are using only one variable "formInput" ( in case of Contact component ) and "inputVal" ( in case of Input component ) but you have number of input fields from where you need data right.

The simplest way to deal with these kind of cases is to create a datastructure and loop through that.

For eg.

```
// Contact component ( i am making it simple to make you understand the scenario )
<template>
    <div class="form container">
        <form v-on:submit.prevent="sendMail" method="post" class="d-flex row shadow bg-dark border-right border-dark">
            <h3 class="col-12">Contact me</h3>
            <!-- we are looping through our data structure and binding each inputVal to this input -->
            <input v-for="(input, i) in formInputs" :key="i" v-model="input.inputVal">
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Input from "../components/Input";
export default {
    name: "Contact",
    components: {Input},
    data() {
        return {
            formInputs: [
              {inputVal: ''},
              {inputVal: ''},
              {inputVal: ''},
            ],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        sendMail () {
            // You can extract the data from formInputs as per your need
        }
    }
}
</script>
```